# Set joinstyle for each marker produced by matplotlib.pyplot.plot()

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as ppl
ppl.plot([0],[0],marker = (5,1,0), ms = 144, mew = 24, mfc = 'w')
ppl.show()
```

produces this:

[image: star]

How can I set this marker's `joinstyle` to `round`?